# Regex for replacing certain string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am feeling silly but I am totally new to python and I have a task to replace following string pattern with NULL.

String of type "xyz.xyz(1,2,3)" should be replaced with "NULL" (Not double-quotes in both cases).

Something like - String s = " abc xyz.xyz(1, 2, 3) pqr" should become 
s = "abc NULL pqr"

s can contain xyz.xyz(10, 20, 30) or xyz.xyz(1) .. i.e inside bracket anything can appear.

Comment: replace `xyz\.xyz\([^)]*\)` with `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need regular expressions for this:

```
import re

s = 'abc xyz.xyz(1, 2, 3) pqr'

re.sub(r'[a-z]{3}\.{[a-z]{3}\([^)]*\)', 'NULL', s)
```

Explanation:

- `[a-z]{3}` stands for 3 small letters (lower case)
- `\.` escapes the dot, as it is special character
- `[a-z]{3}` again 3 small letters
- `\(` escapes the left parenthesis
- `[^)]*` any character but right parenthesis, 0 or more time
- `\)` escapes the right parenthesis

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation. Started learning regex :)